# Generator to Yield a List

Tags: python, generator

I have three lists of lists, and I'm trying to write a generator function to help me package up values in the same index.

So my lists:

```
list1 = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4],...]
list2 = [[4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7],...]
list3 = [[8, 9, 10], [9, 10, 11],...]
```

My desired output:

```
result1 = [[1, 4, 8], [2, 5, 9],...]
result2 = [[2, 5, 9], [3, 6, 10],...]
result3 = [[3, 6, 10], [4, 7, 11],...]
```

My attempt:

```
def bundle(x, y, z, index):
    for row in x, y, z:
        for item in row[index]:
            yield list(item)
```

I keep getting float is not iterable errors. If i modify it slightly:

```
def bundle(x, y, z, index):
    for row in x, y, z:
        for item in row:
            yield item[index]
```

I get the values I want as one large sequence, but I would prefer to keep them grouped in a nested style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're dealing with large lists, a custom, fully lazy approach would be the following:

```
import itertools as it

def bundle(lists, index):
  return ([b[index] for b in blocks] for blocks in it.izip(*lists))

print list(bundle([[[1, 2, 3],  [2, 3, 4]], 
                   [[4, 5, 6],  [5, 6, 7]], 
                   [[8, 9, 10], [9, 10, 11]]], 
                  0))
# => [[1, 4, 8], [2, 5, 9]]
```

Comment: Fantastic. This works like a charm - and I appreciate how I can pull a specific index here. This is exactly what I was going for

Comment: @PatrickD: Also check the other answer involving `numpy` if you are concerned about performance.

Comment: Yea I created these arrays in Numpy and quickly tested it, Also a nice solution, although it requires me to slice the result to pull out the groupings I want. Still - hardly a big deal

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is by a repeated application of `zip()`:

```
res1, res2, res3 = zip(*(zip(*x) for x in zip(list1, list2, list3)))
```

This uses `zip(list1, list2, list3)` to create a sequence of matrices, `zip(*x)` to transpose each of this matrices, and a final `zip()` to unpack to the three resulting sequences.  (I don't think this approach is very efficient.)

Answer (score 2):

If you're dealing with numeric values then you could use numpy's transposition method to achieve what you want:

```
import numpy
numpy.array([list1,list2, list3]).T
```